# Downloading file from webview returns HTML content not the actual file

Tags: java, android, webview, download

I am using a downloadListener to download a file from a webview. The filename is correctly recognized, however the html content is downloaded. In case it is relevant, I am trying to download an .apk file.

```
      webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        InputStream is;
                        try {

                            final String filename= URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);

                            Log.d("download","filename: "+filename);//filename is correct


                            URL u = new URL(url);
                            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                            con.connect();
                            is = con.getInputStream();


                            // Path and File where to download the APK
                            File apk = new File(getFilesDir(),filename);
                            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(apk);

                            // Save file from URL
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                            int len = 0;
                            long total=0;

                            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                output.write(buffer, 0, len);
                                total += len;
                            }

                            output.close();
                            is.close();

                        }
                        catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
```

Comment: The question might be dumb, but is `url` pointing to the correct url and are you able to download the file from this url for instance with `curl` or `wget`?

Comment: `to download a file from a webview. ` ? From a server you mean. Or a website.

Comment: Post the html content. Look into the html. What does it tell you? You will have used a redirecting url.

Comment: The download works absolutely fine a browser also the file is correctly recognized otherwise it wouldn't return it's name.

Comment: @blackapps In a regular browser the file will be downloaded and url is redirected. However I am not sure if that is causing any trouble.

Comment: Then use the redirected url instead.

Comment: @blackapps The redirected url is however not the url that is providing the download. In fact the redirect is from the url that is providing the download to a different url.

Comment: You should find the url for the apk.

Comment: Well I have the url and it is the correct one. The reported MIME type by the server also correct. The main issue is why the inputstream is returning the html content and not the file content.

Comment: If it was the correct url there would not be any html to begin with.

Comment: Further i asked you to look in the html source and/or post the content which you both did not. So we dont know what you get. Is it an error page? What is its content? You keep it secret?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The solution is to add the **cookie** as well as the user-agent to the request property.

```
String cookie = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
con.setRequestProperty("cookie",cookie);
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",userAgent);
```